# Update returns different than 1 row count in store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, rowcount

I have created a store procedure in MySQL (MariaDB) to UPDATE a specific row (just one row) but the row count after the UPDATE returns a value different than one (no rows updated) when all parameter values are the same than last same excecution, i mean when values did not change since previous execution.

Hope you understand that im trying to say When i pass the same parameter values than the last query executed before the procedure returns row count different than 1. its looks like the UPDATE doesn't work because there is nothing to change (all parameters are the same than the before execution) this is my MySQL mariaDB script

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_actualizarOpFicha3(
IN _numero INT,
IN _tipo  INT,
IN _status_op INT, 
IN _status_vta VARCHAR(1),
IN _fecha DATE,
IN _hora VARCHAR(5),
IN _paciente VARCHAR(40),
IN _cirujano VARCHAR(5),
IN _operacion VARCHAR(5),
IN _centro VARCHAR(5),
IN _vendedor VARCHAR(5),
IN _asistente VARCHAR(5),
IN _observ VARCHAR(80),
IN _observ1 VARCHAR(80),
IN _observ2 VARCHAR(80),
IN _obs_ctro VARCHAR(80),
IN _rut_cli VARCHAR(11),
IN _nom_cli VARCHAR(50),
IN _lista_p INT,
IN _n_informe INT,
IN _n_ocompra VARCHAR(15),
IN _sucursal VARCHAR(5),
IN _estado VARCHAR(1),
IN _obs_desp1 VARCHAR(80),
IN _proceso INT,
IN _sub_proc INT,
IN _req_asist INT,
IN _desp_insum INT,
OUT _res_up INT,
OUT mensaje VARCHAR(30) )



BEGIN
DECLARE countRow INT;

START TRANSACTION;

  UPDATE mae_opera 
 SET tipo=_tipo, status_op=_status_op, status_vta=_status_vta, fecha=_fecha, 
 hora=_hora, paciente=_paciente, 
                cirujano=_cirujano, operacion=_operacion, centro=_centro, 
 vendedor=_vendedor, asistente=_asistente, observ=_observ,
                observ1=_observ1, observ2=_observ2, obs_ctro=_obs_ctro, 
rut_cli=_rut_cli, nom_cli=_nom_cli,
                lista_p=_lista_p, n_informe=_n_informe, n_ocompra=n_ocompra, 
sucursal=_sucursal, obs_desp1=_obs_desp1, estado=_estado,
                proceso=_proceso, sub_proc=_sub_proc, req_asist=_req_asist,  
 desp_insum=_desp_insum
  WHERE numero = _numero;

  SET countRow =  ROW_COUNT();

  IF countRow = 1 THEN
    COMMIT;
    SET mensaje = 'Se actualizó correctamente la OP ';

   ELSE
     ROLLBACK;
     SET mensaje = 'Ocurrió un error al intentar actualizar la OP ';


  END IF;
```

Comment: could you also show us your procedure call code ?

Comment: If numero has duplicates (more than one row) it will never update. It only will work if  _numero only appears one time in the column numero, because it makes the UPDATE on a block

Comment: If a row does not get changed, MySQL will treat it as not updated. That behaviour is coherent: such an unchanged row will e.g. not fire `on update` triggers either. If you want to catch updates to more than 1 row, do not assume `<>1` is equal to `>1`, but actually check for `>1`. If you want to make sure that there is only ever at mnost one row per numero, add a unique (e.g. primary) key for that column (or check if there might already be one). And a general note: transaction inside a procedure are to be used with care: they do not nest and will commit any open "outside" transaction too.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your responses and sorry about my english. I call the procedure from a Visual Fox Pro 9 form with a  SQLEXEC() command this is the Visual Fox Pro form code: ` SQLExec(datosql, [ Call sp_actualizarOpFicha( ] + ;
      [?numero_op_up, ] + ;`

Comment: @nacho there is no duplicate values in the numero column in the MySQL table and the procedure UPDATEs (it works)  the correct row  (just one) when some parameter (in parameter) value changed since the last execution .

Comment: @Solarflare do you say that the procedure doesn't update the row cause its detects that there is no changes in relation with the last execution ?

Comment: What it does is: finds the row. Tries to update the row. Realizes that every value is already the same as the new values. Treats it as no update (e.g. doesn't increase the "updated rows" counter, doesn't execute triggers, ...). It doesn't remember the last update statement or something (if that is what you mean), and it requires the same time to find the row; it just compares the current values to the new values and sees they do not require an update (so "0 rows changed")

Comment: Thank you so much @Solarflare!.  As you said  that is exactly whats happening right now, so I need to evaluate when updated rows are 0 and to be sure if the update failed or not. do you have any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I am not really sure what you are trying to actually verify. You could e.g. check if you have >1 row (preventable by a unique key) or no row with that number (you could check for that with `select ... where ...` before the update). If you want to insert a missing number, you may want to try `insert ... on duplicate key update`. "Real errors" (like wrong datatypes, ...) can not be catched that way, you may want to look into error handlers for that. So again: you should explain a bit what you are trying to achieve.